# get image width from upload image and validate to js?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I get image width through upload using php and validate it in js

```
$_FILES['image']
```

and validate it in js if not with size is 560px then return false.. and alert

is possible to use php in js to validate the value from php? any suggestion please help :)

Thanks..

Comment: You seem to be a little confused here, mixing your technologies. You need to upload the file and check it's dimensions in PHP. You can use AJAX requests to achieve this if you're not looking to make page transfers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that what I have now I use jquery-ajax and I wanted to validate the image with when button submit

Answer (score 0):

No; you're confusing client-side and server side programming.

You can however, validate an upload using JavaScript alone (no PHP) using the [HTML5 File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Answer (score 0):

On the serverside you can give this a try:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

This is the serverside, you can use HTML5 on clientside, but only FF, Chrome and Safari support HTML5 files, but not all the functions.

Comment: how can I validate it in jquery-ajax

Comment: You can only upload a file through Ajax with HTML5, and IE does not support this. Do you really want this? Otherwise file upload need to be done with normal HTML.

Comment: how about using js or jquery? or any other suggestion

Comment: They still need to use something to post it, and the JS will still need to use HTML5 if you want to do it through JS.